# Converting JSON file to flatbuffers file

Tags: c#, flatbuffers

I want to convert a JSON file into flatbuffers file (serialize JSON data to flatbuffers data). I already created flatbuffers schema but I do not know where to go from here. The documentation is not clear. It does not contain much detail.

Comment: it;s not quit clear what you mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the [tutorial](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html)? There is a whole section on "Using flatc as a JSON Conversion Tool" with examples.

Comment: You have an array of "Main" objects, there can only be a single root object.

Comment: You can only have a single root object, so your json should be something like:  {
            "tests": {
                "aa": "Test1",
                "bb": "Test2",
                "cc": "Test3",
                "dd": "Test4",
                "ee": "Test5"
            },
            "extras": ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
        },

Comment: You need another root type in that case, if you have multiple "Main" objects. Do something like: table thisIsRoot { mains:[Main];} root_type thisIsRoot;  That is a single object that contains N `Main` objects in the vector.